# Why is /media/preview.png a required file of a M2 theme?

Tags: magento2, theme

The Magento 2 documentation [states](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html) that the `/media` is a required directory for a theme.

> /media         required         This directory contains a theme preview (a screenshot
>   of your theme).

But is this really the case and why?  I have created many theme's which don't have this directory, so why is it **required**?

Answer (score 2):

It is not required. Please check the theme creation documentation clearly states that if you have preview image then only you need it.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

If you have preview image then only you need to add the below section:

```
<media>
  <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
</media>
```

like below:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>New theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
    <media>
      <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
    </media>
</theme>
```

Otherwise you can without preview image like below:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>New theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
</theme>
```

Comment: Interesting, the link to the documentation you have in your answer contradicts the one in my question.  I think this part of the documentation is incorrect to say it's required
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: thanks a ton, it worked.